# How to compare i32 with usize

Tags: rust, compare, insertion-sort

I'm writing a simple insert sort. Here are the relevant codes.

```
fn main() {
    let mut sort_vec = vec![5,2,4,6,1,3];

    for j in 1..sort_vec.len() {
        let key = sort_vec[j];
        
        let mut i = j - 1;
        
        while i > 0 && sort_vec[i] > key {
            sort_vec[i+1] = sort_vec[i];
            i = i - 1;
        }
        sort_vec[i+1] = key;
    }
    println!("{:?}",sort_vec);
}
```

*It's input is [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6].*

The problem was when **while i > 0** becomes **while i >= 0** or **while i > -1**,it won't work.

So is there a problem comparing i32 with usize? I tried some methods and couldn't succeed. So how should I handle it? Be deeply grateful!

Comment: It won't work because `i` is inferred to the type `usize` which is unsigned. For an unsigned type, `i = i - 1` doesn't make sense when `i == 0`, so Rust panics. (In release mode it would overwrap to `usize::MAX`, which also wouldn't do what you want.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `while i > 0` to `while i >= 0` the compiler gives you a warning:

```
warning: comparison is useless due to type limits
--> src\main.rs:9:15
  |
9 |         while i >= 0 && sort_vec[i] > key {
  |               ^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_comparisons)]` on by default
```

and the code panicks at runtime:
`thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to subtract with overflow', src\main.rs:11:17`

The problem is that if i goes down to 0 and you try to subtract 1, the integer `i` overflows because its type is `usize` which has to be non-negative.
Because `usize` can't be negative your comparison `i >= 0` is always true (that's the compiler warning).

I would recommend changing the logic a bit: Don't compare the second last element with the next one but compare the last element with the previous one.
So you have to start not at `j - 1` but at `j`, and replace because of that in the following lines `i` in every index with `i - 1`:

- `sort_vec[i]` -> `sort_vec[i - 1]`
- `sort_vec[i + 1]` -> `sort_vec[i]`

working code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut sort_vec = vec![5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3];

    for j in 1..sort_vec.len() {
        let key = sort_vec[j];

        let mut i = j;

        while i > 0 && sort_vec[i - 1] > key {
            sort_vec[i] = sort_vec[i - 1];
            i = i - 1;
        }
        sort_vec[i] = key;
    }
    println!("{:?}", sort_vec);
}
```

Now you can see the unnecessary assignment `let mut i = j`. You could change the head of the for-loop to `for mut j in ...` to remove that and replace all `i` with `j`.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut sort_vec = vec![5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3];

    for mut j in 1..sort_vec.len() {
        let key = sort_vec[j];

        while j > 0 && sort_vec[j - 1] > key {
            sort_vec[j] = sort_vec[j - 1];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        sort_vec[j] = key;
    }
    println!("{:?}", sort_vec);
}
```

Comment: Note that in your two last examples, the `if i == 0` or `if j == 0` tests are redundant since the `while` condition already ensures that they can't be 0.

Comment: thank you. I was sure I deleted them but it looks like i forgot to update the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://graphitemaster.github.io/aau/#the-loop-in-reverse-argument) there's a nice trick (note that in Rust, wrapping arithmetic has to be explicit or it will panic in debug mode):

```rust
while i < j && sort_vec[i] > key {
    sort_vec[i + 1] = sort_vec[i];
    i = i.wrapping_sub(1);
}
sort_vec[i.wrapping_add(1)] = key;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2cb951dbc9a0bd1130de2c1f89520d37).

The idea is that we let `i` underflow then overflow back - but when it'll underflow it will be no longer less than `j`, so the loop will stop.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the nice trick and the `wrapping_sub()`，`wrapping_add()`!!!That's cool! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`i` has type `usize`, so it can *never* be less than 0. Therefore `i >= 0` or `i >= -1` are always true. One way to fix your issue is to use a `for` loop with a reversed range:

```
fn main() {
    let mut sort_vec = vec![5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3];

    for j in 1..sort_vec.len() {
        for i in (0..j).rev() {
            if sort_vec[i+1] < sort_vec[i] {
                sort_vec.swap (i, i+1);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", sort_vec);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=414cb018b21755099db65403fa10a554)

Comment: I know rev(). But when I encountered a problem, I didn't think of this idea. Thank you for sharing!